Why google map is causing recompositon of other composable?
In the below i have Box() composable. Within this, I have GoogleMap() and BottomActionBar() custom composable. The problem is when a marker is added or is in drag state it's causing the BottomActionBar() composbale to recompose the same times the marker is being dragged. The desired result is that BottomActionBar() is recomposed only if the isMarkerInDragState is actually changed but its recomposing even if the marker is in the same state and being dragged. Also why MainMapView() is recomposed because the Google map is scoped to Box composable.
Your help is really appreciated!
@Composable
private fun MainMapView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lastKnownLocation: Location?,
    onMapClick: (LatLng) -> Unit,
    geoPoints: List<LatLng>,
    isMarkerInDragState: Boolean,
    onDragUpdate: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onClearMapButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    onGeoPointUpdate: (MutableList<LatLng>) -> Unit
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(contentPadding),
    ) {

        val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val markers = mutableListOf<Unit>()

        LaunchedEffect(lastKnownLocation) {
            lastKnownLocation?.let {
                cameraPositionState.animate(
                    update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude),
                        18f
                    )
                )
            }
        }

  
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            properties = MapProperties(
                    isMyLocationEnabled = true,
                    mapType = MapType.Hybrid
                ),
            uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
                mapToolbarEnabled = false,
                zoomControlsEnabled = false
            ),
            onMapClick = {
                onMapClick(it)
            }
        ) {

            if (geoPoints.isNotEmpty()) {
                DrawPolygon(points = geoPoints)

                for ((index, point) in geoPoints.withIndex()) {
                    val markerState =
                        rememberMarkerState(position = LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))

                    LaunchedEffect(markerState.position) {

                        val positions = geoPoints.toMutableList()

                        val pointIndex = positions.indexOf(point)

                        if (pointIndex < 0) {
                            return@LaunchedEffect
                        }

                        positions[pointIndex] = markerState.position

                        onGeoPointUpdate(positions)
                   
                    }
                    LaunchedEffect(markerState.dragState) {
                        when (markerState.dragState) {
                            DragState.DRAG -> onDragUpdate(true)
                            DragState.START -> {}
                            DragState.END -> onDragUpdate(false)
                        }
                    }

                    val marker = Marker(
                        state = markerState,
                        visible = true,
                        title = "Point ${index + 1}",
                        draggable = true
                    )

                    markers.add(marker)
                }
            }
        }
   
        BottomActions(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            isVisible = geoPoints.size > 2,
            onClearMapButtonClick = {
                onClearMapButtonClick()
            }
        )
    }
}


I don't quite understand why you are using multiple Launched Effects. But as far as I know, you should not overuse them as per: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/side-effects#:~:text=Due%20to%20the%20different%20possibilities%20effects%20open%20up%20in%20Compose%2C%20they%20can%20be%20easily%20overused.%20Make%20sure%20that%20the%20work%20you%20do%20in%20them%20is%20UI%20related%20and%20doesn%27t%20break%20unidirectional%20data%20flow%20as%20explained%20in%20the%20Managing%20state%20documentation.

I am not able to reproduce your code on my environment. If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, that would be cool.
